# PHP/MongoDB, Unable to update records in a collection

Tags: php, mongodb, codeigniter

I am trying to update records in a mongodb by using php codeigniter, but I am unable to do so.

My controller class:

```
function updatetodb_post(){

$updateddata = array('$set' => array("lang" => "English"));

$this->load->model('data_model');

$uid    = 1;

$this->data_model->updaterecords($uid, $updateddata);

}
```

My Model class:

```
function updaterecords($uid, $updatedata){
    $this->load->library('mongo_db'); 

    $recoundsbyuid = $this->mongo_db->get_where($this->_testcollectoin, array("uid" => $uid));

    $this->mongo_db->update($this->_testcollectoin, $recoundsbyuid, $updatedata);

}
```

data that I want to update in a collectoin:

```
$data = array(
                  "uid" => "1",
                  "type" => "Movie",
                  "genre" => "Action"
                  );
```

where `_testcollectoinis` my collection name. I want to add one more field (`lang`) to the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use below commands to update with given data

```
$this->mongo_db->where(array("uid" => $uid))->set($updatedata)->update($this->_testcollectoin);
```